# Dark Souls 1 executable has stopped working

Tags: steam, dark-souls, games-for-windows-live

I reinstalled DS1 toady and right at the start DS1 crashed.

With the error message : "dark souls PTDE executable has stopped working"

I already did some research and apperently Games for Windows Live is the Problem.

What i already did:

```
-Resinstall the Game
-Reinstall the GFWL stuff
-Used the xlive.dll fix
```

My Pc:

```
-Windows 7 64 bit
-Game is on Steam
```

What i read and tried but did not work:

```
-https://steamcommunity.com/app/211420/discussions/0/558747288212070021/
-https://steamcommunity.com/app/211420/discussions/0/864973123391542749/?l=german
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dark Souls Prepare to Die Edition already doesn't work with GFWL.

In options in Steam select beta versions and choose 2. It may help.